# A point charge is kept at the centre of a metallic inducted spherical shell. Then why is the net induced charge on the sphere zero?

Tags: electrostatics

Why is the net induced charge in a inducted spherical shell zero when a point charge is kept in the centre of that sphere?

Comment: If charge can neither flow onto or off the spherical shell the net charge cannot change.

Comment: Would "inducted" be "conductive"?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I think the OP must have meant "isolated" since that is the only way the conclusion holds.

Answer (score 2):

The net charge induced is zero for an isolated spherical shell since the spherical shell can't acquire or give up charge.

It's like a poker game with your friends, the money can only move around. Some might lose money some might gain money but the net change in money for all of you is zero.

If the spherical shell were grounded or held at a constant potential things would be different because charge could flow to or from the shell.

Answer (score 1):

The net charge induced is 0 because charge kept at the centre can attract negative charges of shell( electron) towards the inner surface but the outer surface will have equal amount of positive charge. So net charge induced on total shell is zero. The charge and the centre can make the shell polar but can't induce net charge on the shell